# Why were Janeway's and Tuvok's command codes still active?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In "Unimatrix Zero", Janeway and Tuvok's command codes are still active, even though they're on a dangerous mission in the Borg Queen's Command Cube. Wouldn't it be SOP for the security of starships to lock out command codes under similar situations? Chakotay even remarks after Borg weapons are cutting though Voyager's hull: *"They must have gotten Tuvok's command codes."*

Was this malfeasance on the part of Chakotay?

Comment: In TNG Gambit part 2 Troi remarks when Riker tries to get through Enterprise-D's sheilds "This makes no sense, he should know that once he was captured, his command codes would have been locked out" So it's certainly Starfleet SOP.

Comment: As far as I can tell, in "Gambit" it's at least a day between encounters, whereas in "Unimatrix Zero" it's a matter of hours between the plan being hatched and it going wrong. It might've been overlooked - it's not like *Voyager*'s command crew was sitting around doing nothing during that time.

Comment: @Cadence part of that plan was to allow themselves to be assimilated, so locking out their codes should have been on the table. They had the time for the Doctor and Seven to develop an inhibitor to allow them to retain their individuality. So if they had the time and insight to do that, they certainly had the time to lock out the command codes, which is easily done by telling the cumputer. The three of them were curcial to the operations of Voyager and had very high clearance. So it was just incompetence and it caused substantial damage to Voyager and cost the lives of several crew members.

Comment: Yep, you're right.

Comment: maybe Starfleet has to handle resetting command codes and Voyager didn't get the chance to let them know to do so?

Comment: @NkCampbell Security clearances could be deleted, as Tuvok did when he believed he was no longer fit for duty. (VOY: "Meld") So clearly Starfleet captains and other officers it was at their discretion. I'm sure they would have explaining to do if they locked at command codes if it wasn't warranted. I

Comment: do security clearances == command codes? Clearance is generally intraship wheras command code is intership, no (thus maybe requiring starfleet)?

Comment: Security codes are valid in the discussion because that's what what the Borg Queen ripped out of Tuvok's head, to get pass the new modified shields. So to update, command and security codes should have been locked out for the duration of the mission. As Voy ep Meld showed us an officer could delete their own clearance, which is exy what Janeway, Tuvok and Torres should have done

Comment: that makes sense - thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

Being that there is no answer yet, I decided to give a wack at my opinion.
Essentially it’s a plothole. It’s a problem with the writing. It makes no sense in universe but it moves the episode along. Issues like this happen multiple times in Star Trek. When you’re under a strict deadline. There isn’t the budget or culture for things to be airtight then things like this either get through or are used intentionally. It can make sense on a surface level “They’re his codes so of course kidnapping him to use the codes is reasonable” but any more thought than that and it totally falls apart.
But be it a plothole and or bad writing, in universe it makes that oversight conanical that Voyager command staff had dropped the ball and were incompetent. It's canon because of this oversight Voyager took substantial damage and it cost the death of crew members.